# UNIX: How to zip a file as soon as it's landed in a directory

Tags: zip

We are getting these huge files from a source system which fills up the storage. Requirement is that these files should be compressed(zip/gz) as soon as files are landed in the file system. These are huge files so I need a reliable way to know that file has been copied completely as I don't want to end up messing up the file copy process.

From Google search, people have suggested:

1. Run a loop for every minute and check the file size and if it hasn't changed then you know it's done and zip it.
2. Similar logic but using file creation time and modified time using stat command : https://superuser.com/questions/612099/unix-commands-to-get-last-modified-date-and-size-of-file-folder-not-ls
3. Using lsof

What other solutions are available?

EDIT:
Found a solution on Stack:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36815621/2560010

Comment: another option is to use a filesystem supporting compression, such as `zfs` or `btrfs` for example

Comment: Is this on a Linux-based system or something else?

Comment: What creates those files? Where do you get them from?

Comment: I don’t know an easy way to do it. Either use a self compressing file system like indicated, or a program with the `inotify` set of syscalls.  These syscalls wait for something and warn : something new has happened on this file. It warns closed files which was written then no need to verify if the file is in a stable state (which is not a safe way to proceed).

Comment: The source system how send the files?

Comment: If you're using a filesystem that supports it, `inotify` will let you do this. Read `man -k inotify;man inotifywatch`.

Comment: More details: 
1. Files are coming from Mainframe so I don't have control over that.
2. Yes, this is Linux where i need to run this process
3. It's a shared system so I can't install inotify or zfs

Comment: [That](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36815067/2344631) is an awful set of solutions. If you [update your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/685185/edit) here you might get some useful replies

Comment: `inotify` is a fairly standard utility. Are you sure that your administrator won't run `apt install inotify-tools` or `yum install inotify-tools` (from epel)? Doesn't hurt to ask.